# FactoryGirl RSpec No method error when creating factory object where factory sets a property of that object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Anytime I create a Factory object, I get this error where the factory sets a property on that object -- in this case 'name'. Why???

businesses.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :business do

    factory :business_main do
      name "Dave's Toys"
    end
  end
end
```

businesses table

```
        Column        |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        
----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                     | not null default nextval('businesses_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                 | character varying(255)      | 
 address_line1        | character varying(255)      | 
 address_line2        | character varying(255)      | 
 city                 | character varying(255)      | 
 state                | character varying(255)      | 
 zip                  | character varying(255)      |
```

business_spec.rb

```
...
business  = Factory(:business_main)
...

 # Failure/Error: business  = Factory(:business_main)
 # NoMethodError:       undefined method `name=' for #<Business:0x007fc991684590>
```

-

```
Using rails (3.1.3) 
Using factory_girl (2.3.2) 
Using factory_girl_rails (1.4.0)
Using rspec-core (2.7.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.7.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.7.0) 
Using rspec (2.7.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.7.0)
```

Comment: it's pretty strange. how do you run your specs?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by nesting `business` and `business_main` factories like that?

Comment: Ack, I hadn't run my migrations in the test database!

Comment: @99miles, yeah, it was my first guess

Answer (score 7):

Run `rake db:test:clone` and then all test DB columns will be mapped properly to Active Record methods.